# HTTP Tunneling in Android App

Tags: php, android, http-tunneling

In my android app, I am calling PHP Web API over HTTP but anyone can see HTTP traffic by sniffer / proxy.

So I want to create HTTP tunneling through android to call my PHP Web API.

I tried to search some sample code on Google to implement HTTP tunneling in android programming.